# Showing that $\int_E (g-f) = \int_E g - \int_E f$ for $0 \leq f \leq g $ with $\int_E f < \infty$ and $E$ measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Show by first principles (using the definition of a lebesgue integral for non-negative functions as the supremum of integrals for simple functions which are bounded by these functions) that for a measurable set $E$ and $0 \leq f \leq g $ with $\int_E f < \infty$, we have that 1) $g-f$ is measurable 2) $0 \leq \int_E (g-f) \leq \infty$ and

3)$$ \int_E (g-f) = \int_E g - \int_E f$$ as extended real numbers.

I know how to do 1 and 2 but proving three using first principles seems difficult if I dont use approximations by simple functions and limit theorems.

Comment: Hint: In general if $f$ and $h$ are nonnegative and measurable then $\int_E(f+h)=\int_Ef+\int_Eh$. Apply this with $h:=g-f$.

Comment: I understand your point and initially approached the problem like this, however the book has not yet _proved_ that $\int_E (f+h) = \int_E f + \int_E h$ for general, non-negative measurable functions. Finite additivity is proved only for simple functions uptil this point.

Comment: I think it is inevitable first to prove that $\int(f+h)=\int f+\int g$ for measuble nonnegative functions. This by exploiting the fact that it has been proved for simple functions already and secondly the fact that by definition: $$\int f=\sup(\{\int u\mid u\text{ simple and measurable with }0\leq u\leq f\})$$

Comment: If you only have the def for positive $f$ you are almost forced to consider $f^+$ and $f^-$